# Translating radial data to a cartesian grid for surface plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of data whose components correspond to the potential at some radial distance r on a 2D grid. The data corresponds to data points in polar coordinates and is symmetric in the theta component

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = np.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 99)
#Data looks like:
V = np.array([9.0,...,0.0])

x = np.linspace(-5.0,5.0,99)
y = np.linspace(-5.0,5.0,99)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

I would like to create a surface plot of the data in (x,y) space, however to use matplotlib you need a grid of data points corresponding to the potential at each (x,y) location. Given that I have a set of data measured in (r,theta) space, how can I create a surface plot?

Comment: What is theta and where is `theta` in the code? Do you want to plot a 2D plot or 3D plot? What should the plot show? Should it show the data as height of the surface above the ground (3D) or as color (2D) or something else?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, it should show the data as the height of the surface above the (x,y) plane. I have data which is sampled at different values of r and is symmetric with theta, i.e. for a fixed r each data point is independent of theta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to tranform your data to cartesian coordinates first and create a value array of the same shape as the meshgrid by repeating the value `V` for each theta.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

r = np.linspace(1.0, 5.0, 99)
V = np.sqrt(np.sinc(r-0.5)**2) # your data here (same length as r)


theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
R, Theta = np.meshgrid(r,theta)
X = R * np.cos(Theta)
Y = R * np.sin(Theta)
Z = np.tile(V,(len(theta),1))

norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=Z.min(), vmax=Z.max())
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, facecolors=plt.cm.RdYlGn(norm(Z)))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious though, it seems that Z is an array whose rows correspond to the r position and columns correspond to theta position. I don't quite understand how or why matplotlib converts this data to correspond to some x,y coordinate.

Comment: The x,y coordinates are given in the arrays `X` and `Y`. `Z` holds the corresponding values at those positions. Hence a point with coodinates `X[i,j], Y[i,j]` will have the value `Z[i,j]`.